# How to prove or disprove $\mathbb P[X\in[\mathbb E[X]-a\sigma(X),\mathbb E[X]+a\sigma(X)]]\leq\frac{1}{a^2} $?

Tags: random-variables, standard-deviation, stochastic-approximation

$X$ is a random variable in $\mathcal{L^2}$, $a>0$ and $\sigma(X)$ is the standard deviation of $X$.

Comment: If $\in $ is changed to $\notin$ then the inequality is true and it can be proved by applying Chebycheff's inequality to $Y=\frac {X-EX} {\sigma (X)}$

Answer (score 2):

False. As $a \to \infty $ LHS tends to 1 and RHS to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X$ be constant so that LHS equals $1$. Further let $a$ be large enough to satisfy $\frac1{a^2}<1$.

Comment: Or more simply to state, let $a>1$.